# score is not increasing when question is answered correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have added a dropdown with both numerical and percentage scores in my scoreboard score component, but the score doesn't seem to increase when a question is answered correctly, it just shows 0/4 or 0%. I'm including my code below and please could you see my **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app)** and help to fix this issue. Thank you.

score template:

```
<ng-container class="score">
  <div class="mat-menu">
    <mat-toolbar>...</mat-toolbar>
  </div>
   <section class="scoreboard-score">
    <span class="scoreboard" i18n>
      {{ score$ | async }}
    </span>
  </section>
</ng-container>
```

in score.component.ts file:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     ...
      this.correctAnswersCountSubscription = this.correctAnswersCount$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
          .subscribe((correctAnswersCount: number) => {
            this.correctAnswersCount = correctAnswersCount;
        });
     this.numericalScore();
  }

  numericalScore(): void {
    this.score = this.correctAnswersCount.toString() + "/" + this.totalQuestions.toString();
    this.score$ = of(this.score);
  }

  percentageScore(): void {
    this.score = Math.ceil((this.correctAnswersCount / this.totalQuestions) * 100).toString() + "%";
    this.score$ = of(this.score);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stackblitz is different from what u pasted here. But I think the case is u need to call  `this.score$ = of(this.score);` only when this.correctAnswersCount$ is emitting new value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-nuhkb7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainers%2Fscoreboard%2Fscore%2Fscore.component.ts

```
numericalScore(): void {
    this.correctAnswersCountSubscription = this.correctAnswersCount$.subscribe(
      (correctAnswersCount: number) => {
        this.correctAnswersCount = correctAnswersCount;
        this.score =
          this.correctAnswersCount.toString() +
          "/" +
          this.totalQuestions.toString();
        this.score$ = of(this.score);
      }
    );
  }
```